# Reduce precision of values in XML document

Tags: python, xml, xslt, awk, xml-parsing

I have a large XML document (KML, to be accurate) that describes geographic coordinates; a snippet below should give you an idea how it looks like. The issue here is that coordinates are in double precision (16 decimal places), which causes a lot of problems in further processing (besides, last decimal place is actually tenth of a nanometer - our GPS are not THAT precise).

I was looking for any way of reducing the precision to a given value, e.g. 5 decimal places give us a meter accuracy. I tried parsing the XML in Python (with lxml), changing values and saving new document, but in the process document's formatting changes a lot and somehow breaks further processing.

Therefore I am looking for a method of reducing the precision in-place, so that the values are changed in the original file. I thought AWK should do the trick, but regrettably my attempts were to no avail.

Here is an example of [my XML](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2q-cMmm5PYjSHdtNDNOQkMtdFk/edit?usp=sharing).

```
<Document xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Folder><name>Export_Output02</name>
        <Placemark>
            <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
            <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#Export_Output02">
                <SimpleData name="species">1312</SimpleData>
                <SimpleData name="area">7848012</SimpleData>
                <SimpleData name="irrep_area">0.00000012742</SimpleData>
                <SimpleData name="groupID">2</SimpleData>
            </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
            <MultiGeometry>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>-57.843052746056827,-33.032934004012787 -57.825312079170494,-33.089724736921667 -57.888494029914156,-33.073777852969904 -57.843052746056827,-33.032934004012787</coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>-57.635769389832561,-33.032934004012787 -57.618028722946228,-33.089724736921667 -57.681210673689904,-33.073777852969904 -57.635769389832561,-33.032934004012787</coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </MultiGeometry>
        </Placemark>
    </Folder>
</Document>
```

[Edit]

My Python code:

```
import glob
import argparse
from pykml import parser
from pykml.helpers import set_max_decimal_places

arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Script for batch reduction of precision of KML files', prog='KML precision reducer')

arg_parser.add_argument('-p', '--precision', type=int, default=5, help='Desired precision')
arg_parser.add_argument('-d', '--directory', default='./', help='Path to KML files')

args = arg_parser.parse_args()

path_to_kml = glob.glob(args.directory + '*.kml')
precision = args.precision

for kml_file in path_to_kml:
    print 'Processing ' + kml_file
    with open(kml_file) as file_read:
        doc = parser.parse(file_read)

    max_decimals={'longitude': precision, 'latitude': precision,}

    for element in doc.iter("*"):
        set_max_decimal_places(element, max_decimals)

    out_filename = kml_file.replace('.kml', '_out.kml')

    with open(out_filename, 'w') as file_write:
       doc.write(file_write, pretty_print=True, with_tail=True)
```

Comment: The "formatting" of an XML document should not matter as long as the only difference is non-significant whitespace and empty tags (single or paired).  What "breaks" downstream when you use lxml?

Comment: @JimGarrison I thought the same. Regrettably I can't tell what exactly goes wrong. Conversion to Google Fusion Table, which is the ultimate goal, goes without errors, though the final result has missing geometry (so I get a map without any points). I should add that Google Fusion Tables impose many limits, so it very well might be that the number of lines is too large or something like that.

Comment: You could use XSLT to transform the coordinates.

Comment: If you want help you should post the Python code and a sample of the output you get.

Comment: @helderdarocha Since I am completely unfamiliar with XSLT, could you give more concrete example I could follow? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. I'll post one. If you are interested you should also add a XSLT tag to your question, since you will attract solutions by others as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt). The stylesheet below uses [XSLT 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/). This is also possible using XSLT 1.0, but it doesn't have the `tokenize()` function which I used here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:gis="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
    version="2.0">

    <!-- This is an identity transform template - it copies all the nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- this template has precedence over the identity template for the `coordinates` nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="gis:coordinates">
        <xsl:copy> <!-- it copies the element --> 
        <xsl:variable name="coords" select="tokenize(.,' ')"/> <!-- saves coordinate pairs in variable -->
        <xsl:for-each select="$coords"> <!-- for each coordinate pair, formats the values before and after the comma -->
            <xsl:value-of select="round(number(substring-before(.,','))*100000) div 100000"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> <!-- puts the comma back between the coords -->
            <xsl:value-of select="round(number(substring-after(.,','))*100000) div 100000"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text> <!-- puts the space back if it's not the last coord -->
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I added some comments above explaining how it works.

If you apply it to your sample document, it will truncate the coordinates to five decimal digits. Here is an example showing the `coordinates` element after transformation:

```
<LinearRing>
    <coordinates>-57.84305,-33.03293 -57.82531,-33.08972 -57.88849,-33.07378 -57.84305,-33.03293</coordinates>
</LinearRing>
```

Here is a **[XSLT Fiddle](http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rLR)** with a working result.

I pasted your *full XML* in the XML Playground above and it worked. I just wasn't able to save the fiddle with your file to link it here because the file is too big, but you can try pasting it there. It takes some 40 seconds to transform the full file.

I don't know about XSLT 2.0 support in Python, but you can run the transform using a command line tool such as [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/), or call a program in Java or other language that has XSLT 2.0 support (or, if you are looking for a solution for just this specific problem, possibly solve it with the online tools).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It does precisely what I needed. Indeed I used Saxon tool to apply transformation.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those instances when you *can* mix XML and regexes and get away with it:

```
import re

coords = re.compile("([-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]{6,}),([-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]{6,})")

def five_digits(match):
    return "%.5f,%.5f" % tuple(float(g) for g in match.groups())

with open("source.xml") as source, open("target.xml", "w") as target:
    source_xml = source.read()
    target_xml = re.sub(coords, five_digits, source_xml)
    target.write(target_xml)
```

The pattern `coords` matches pairs of co-ordinates with six or more decimal places each, the function `five_digits` returns those co-ordinates reformatted to five places, and the `re.sub` call uses those two to make the replacements.

Comment: Thanks! However, with your solution I still end up writing new XML and therefore "breaking" magic Google Fusion Tables limits. That's whay I was looking for something in-place, so that I do not need to write new file. Besides, wouldn't your approach change any number, not only coordinates?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski Since you suggested using AWK, I assumed you were okay with modifying an actual file. You're right that the previous version of my answer rounded all 6-digit-plus decimals it found; I've modified it to only round co-ordinate pairs now.

Comment: I guess 'too_precise' should be 'coords', right? Sorry for the dumb question, but I did not see regex for 10 years :). When I replace it, then I get TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable on  return "%.5f,%.5f" % tuple(float(g) for g in match.groups)

Comment: @LukaszTracewski argh, too hasty in editing - fixed now. Yes, `too_precise` should have been `coords` (and I forgot to actually call `match.groups`).

Comment: Now it works like a charm! Both yours and helderdarocha answers will make to the small toolkit I am preparing for conversion of shapefiles to Google fusion tables. GIS community will be grateful - thanks!